# Resizing UIImageView Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, uiimageview, aspect

I want to resize the UIImageView and keeping its aspect ratio.

What have I done is just using Center Horizontally and Vertically constraints on storyboard.

[image: Constraint layout]

If let say I using top and bottom, leading and trailing constraints, it doesn't keep the frame same as image ratio. The red border represents UIImageView frame.

[image]

The result will be like this if the image is in suitable size

[image]

However, the frame sometimes will be out of view range, but the ratio is maintained with image.

[image]

I have done searching everywhere and mostly ended with suggesting with `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill`, which does not fulfill my needs.

Comment: You should use `.scaleAspectFit` instead, if you want the image to stay within the bounds.

Comment: The downside being it will always make the image as long or as wide as the imageView.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri `.scaleAspectFit` still does not give required result. it does not provide proper image frame bound.

Comment: So you want the image to be small for the smaller cases and fit the screen when it exceeds the screen size?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri as long as it not out of screen range and the image and frame is intact, either the image is in landscape or portrait.

Comment: Set less than or equal constraints for your imageView's height and width. `.scaleAspectFit` should give you what you need after that.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri okay then do i need to put constraints on trailing, leading, top and bottom?

Comment: Either you set less than or equal to constraints for `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom` **OR** for `height` and `width`.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri emm still not working. the constraints for both does not satisfied, and the imageview is out of view if its bigger.

Comment: Please share your code by editing the question.